# Is changing/editing the url of a web shortcut impossible with Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Over a decade ago I remember being able to edit a web shortcut with Internet Explorer. I can do the same today with Firefox and have always done as far back as I remember using Firefox.

The well mastered magic to changing a url of an existing shortcut (aka bookmark) is right-click on the shortcut, select Properties, and change the url presented in an editable TextBox.

Unless I am missing something very obvious, I see no way that I can do the same with Microsoft Edge. Yes, I get the subtle differences with the new UWP apps (which Microsoft Edge is) but don't think changing a url is such a big challenge nor would I consider such an option to be dropped (on moving from IE to Edge), because updating a url is a most common task. For example, I have a SO link on my toolbar and I would like to change where it's pointing (a different active topic I would like to follow) without disturbing the URL button on my toolbar (or under a menu).

Is it impossible to edit a web shortcut with Microsoft Edge?

Comment: It's not possible, yet. Not even in the Creators Update insider builds. You may use a program called [EdgeManage](http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeManage.html) to manage Edge bookmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that implementing the ability to change a bookmark's target is a trivial programming task, it goes without saying that Microsoft has no done that trivial task. Hence, no, you cannot change a bookmark's target in Edge.

Blame Microsoft. They deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there *is* a way to do it... but it requires a free 3rd-party application.

Take a look at this article to see if this is something that you'd be interested in: http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeManage.html

PS: I am the author

*PPS: The next release of Windows 10 (the so-called Fall Creators Update) will almost certainly include this feature.*